# Update functional component when new data pushed to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional react component:

```
function Messages() {
    return(
         data.messages.map(function(obj, i){return(
            <div className="messages_wrapper" key={i}>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        )})
    )
}

export default Messages;
```

...which shows all messages contained in an array called data. The data object looks like this:

```
export const data = {
    messages : [
        {
            // data here
        },
        {
            // data here
        },
        ....
}
```

When I push a new message into **data**:

```
messages.data.push({
    "message" : "this is a new message"
})
```

...I want the above component to **rerender** in the DOM. I believe this is what Hooks are for, specifically the UseEffect hook, but it does not seem to work.

How can I have the functional component rerender itself when the data array has a new element pushed into it? Is there a way for the component to "listen" to changes in the data object and rerender itself on the change?

```
const [count, newMessage] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    // do something with data array here?
});
```

Comment: where does `data.messages` come from?

Comment: is the "data" variable is passed to the "Messages" component as "props" , because I found not see if there are any props.

Comment: what pushes new elements to the array?

Comment: @MattAft please see updated question. data is an object and messages is an array.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova does it matter? A button has an onClick which calls a function that pushes the new message from the contents of a textarea.

Comment: Yes it does, whatever makes the change will need to communicate it to the component. useEffect will not help you here. Is this button in the same component?

Comment: you need to call your state setting function not `push`

Comment: store the messages in local state or global state via redux/context etc and the component will be able to pick up on the changes. but you would also have to return a new array instead of pushing

Comment: @MattAft redux / context is way overboard for this question. normal react state aka `useState` is what's needed here to start

Answer (score 0):

Mutating state data(more specifically reference types) in react is a **no-no** and your `messages` array is indeed a state for your component as it depends on it and its changes. You should track your `messages` in your component(or any parent component and pass it down to the concerned component through `props`) and mutate **the reference** to it, **not** the array contents themselves(why? explained below).

Here is a sample:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Messages() {
   const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

   return (
      {messages.map((message, index) => {
         return (
            <div className="messages_wrapper" key={i}>
               /* use message here*/
            </div>
         );
      })}
   );
}

export default Messages;
```

Now, depending on how you want to add new messages to the `messages` collection(event handler or any other type of effect) you should provide react(through the `setMessages` function) with **updated reference** and it will handle the re-render of the component automatically for you.

Sample:

```
const handleClick = () => {
   const newMessage = {
      /* message body */
   };

   setMessages((messages) => [...messages, newMessage]);
};
```

This way every time the `handleClick` handler gets executed, the `setMessages` function will create a new array containing all the current messages + the new message you want to push and pass that array reference to your state `messages` variable. React will notice the `messages` variable reference have changed and will re-execute the function component's body thus re-rendering and presenting your updated visualization.

Write your logic as if all your state is immutable and the only way to change it is supplying a new reference entirely. This is important as it ensures react can track and handle your state changes properly and efficiently. The engine doesn't track changes **in** the objects themselves and there is a very good performance and maintainability reason for that behaviour. That's the reason you shouldn't mutate the contents of reference variables.

So, in short, `useState` is a hook for maintaining state. `useEffect`, on the other hand, is concerned with executing side effects(fetching data, making subscriptions and such).

It is an important point if those messages are shared data and are being used by more than one unrelated components or are being consumed by a single component only. In the latter case you can store them in the component state as shown above and load them on component mount from the related service or whatever you have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Messages() {
   const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
      const async fetchMessages = () => {
         /* fetch logic */

         const messagesResult = await _service.getMessages(); /* fetch logic */;

         setMessages(messagesResult);
      }

      fetchMessages();
   }, []);

   return (
      {messages.map((message, index) => {
         return (
            <div className="messages_wrapper" key={i}>
               /* use message here*/
            </div>
         );
      })}
   );
}

export default Messages;
```

In the former case, you should track the state in a single place and notify interested components for the changes(by either passing the state as `props` to child components if they're related or maybe context/state management library if you have a more complex case).

Comment: But how can I export the setMessages function so that something outside the component can pass the new message?

Comment: @Cybernetic Depends if that 'something' is a child of the component that holds the state. If so, you can pass the `setMessages` function down to the children using `props` and they can invoke it thus updating the state in their parent which will cause a re-render of the whole component tree below the parent including itself. If, however, you need to update the messages from other unrelated(non-child components) as well, the most painless solution would be using React Context or a State Management library, like stated in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a state messages like this:

```
[messagesState, setMessagesState] = useState({ messages : [
        {
            // data here
        },
        {
            // data here
        },
        ....
    ]})
```

When you add new item in your array, don't use mutation, use mutable data like this:

```
const messagesUpdated =  {
messages : [...messagesState, newMessage]
}
setMessagesState(messagesUpdated)
```